# Can I create or use the view controller like SLComposeViewController for the social networks other than Twitter and Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, twitter

Can I create or use the view controller like SLComposeViewController for the social networks other than Twitter and Facebook? I want to have the similar look for all of the social networks interactions. Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll get something like this in iOS 8 with sharing extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 7 there is just four social services integrated with SLComposeViewController.

```
NSString *const SLServiceTypeFacebook; 
NSString *const SLServiceTypeTwitter; 
NSString *const SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo; 
NSString *const SLServiceTypeTencentWeibo;
```

If you want to share some data in vk.com, you should check this official VK SDK for iOS: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk

It is pretty well documented. I hope you are one the right way now :)

Comment: Yes, I already use it, but it doesn't provide any specific view controller to type the message. This is why I asked this question here

Comment: it has VKShareDialogController, you should stick to it

Comment: @FrozenHeart oh wow it was added 9 hours ago, congratulations )) this is what you need

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Can you provide an example of how to use it? In case of just [[VKShareDialogController alloc] init] and presentViewController there is no any buttons in the view

Comment: As you can see, I'm surprized about the brand new DialogController, so I'm not experienced with it.

Comment: Try to use method `- (void)presentIn:(UIViewController *)viewController;` which has a note: `Correctly presents current view controller in another`

Comment: Can you also answer this question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833698/what-can-i-do-if-isavailableforservicetype-method-returns-no

Comment: Also can you provide any of your contacts for me, please? Skype / email / etc

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation. These are the following options:

`Service Type Constants
NSString *const SLServiceTypeFacebook; 
NSString *const SLServiceTypeTwitter; 
NSString *const SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo; 
NSString *const SLServiceTypeTencentWeibo;`

Comment: Yes, but I want to use such class for the VK.com that is not listed here