# How to correctly create animation with the moving label and disable any UI interractions while it is in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to create animation with the moving label in Objective-C for iOS. The animation should appear as the user taps the certain button. Also I need to disable any UI interractions while the animation is in progress. This is what I do to achieve this behavior:

1.Create UILabel object in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller, set all required fields to the appropriate values and make it hidden:

```
plusScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
plusScoreLabel.text = @"+10";
plusScoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:12.0/255.0 green:144.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
plusScoreLabel.hidden = YES;
plusScoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:plusScoreLabel];

uiInteractionsDisabled = NO;
```

2.Then I call animateWithDuration:animation:completion method on the button pressed action like this:

```
uiInteractionsDisabled = YES;
[plusScoreLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(buttonToChoose.center.x, buttonToChoose.center.y)];
plusScoreLabel.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        plusScoreLabel.center = CGPointMake(buttonToChoose.center.x, buttonToChoose.center.y - 50.0f);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        plusScoreLabel.hidden = YES;
    }];
```

3.Add the following check to the each IBAction method:

```
if (uiInteractionsDisabled == YES) {
    return;
}
```

Is there something wrong with this method? Maybe there is a better way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your solution.
If you want something special, you can subclass the CABasicAnimation and override two methods in it:

```
/* Called when the animation begins its active duration. */

- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim;

/* Called when the animation either completes its active duration or
 * is removed from the object it is attached to (i.e. the layer). 'flag'
 * is true if the animation reached the end of its active duration
 * without being removed. */

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag;
```

in addition you can add two block properties to the subclass:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void  (^startBlock)(void) ;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void  (^finishBlock)(void) ;
```

and execute the blocks in overriden methods:

```
- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim{
    if (_startBlock){
        _startBlock();
    }
}
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    if (_finishBlock){
        _finishBlock();
    }
}
```

after that, you can use your custom animation object like that:

```
    MyCustomAnimation* anim = [MyCustomAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    anim.startBlock = ^{uiInteractionsDisabled = YES;};
    anim.finishBlock = ^{uiInteractionsDisabled = NO;};
    [anim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(buttonToChoose.center.x, buttonToChoose.center.y)]];
    [anim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(buttonToChoose.center.x, buttonToChoose.center.y - 50.0f)]];
    [anim setDuration:0.5];
    [plusScoreLabel.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"translationAnimation"];
```

I hope you've learned something new : )

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Can you answer to my other question too, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829839/can-i-create-or-use-the-view-controller-like-slcomposeviewcontroller-for-the-soc