# What can I do if isAvailableForServiceType method returns NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What can I do if `isAvailableForServiceType` method returns NO in case of Twitter, for example?

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    // post message
} else {
    // show some additional screen
}
```

Can I somehow provide the user a standard login / register view or switch him to the iOS settings? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        // 
    } else {
        SLComposeViewController *twitterSignInDialog = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [self presentViewController:twitterSignInDialog animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: When I press "Settings" button in this view controller nothing happens

Comment: Maybe try it on real device

Comment: Thanks. Also can you provide any of your contacts for me, please? Skype / email / etc

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please check your email